# Rating Settings From General Menu Missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rating, documents

I have documents library with different files in the table. I want to add rating column which I learned to do this from this tutorial http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/12/02/how-to-use-rating-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.

Steps which I reproduce:

1. Click on some documents library
2. Click on library tools
3. Click on library settings
4. Here us the problem I cannot see **Rating Settings** from General Settings menu.

What should I do to see this Ratings Settings link ?

Comment: Try to activate publishing feature.

Comment: How can I do this ? Can you share some steps or link ?

Comment: Go to Site Collection Features (Site Actions-> Site Settings -> Site collections features) and activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature. Then go to Site features (Site Actions-> Site Settings -> Manage site features) and activate "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature.

Comment: I red that I should do this Enable-SPFeature Ratings -url http://intranet-test/suppliers/. Do you know where I can put this script or what should I do with it ?

Comment: From this article on the bottom is the script. http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/rating-feature-how-to-activate-fix-ratings-not-updating.html

Comment: You need to copy this script to your sharepoint server and run it with powershell using elevated privileges.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This works fine what you wrote me. Go to Site Collection Features (Site Actions-> Site Settings -> Site collections features) and activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature. Then go to Site features (Site Actions-> Site Settings -> Manage site features) and activate "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it. Thank you. If you have any other additional comments feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to activate publishing feature.